# How to import .csv file to CartoDB using SQL?

Tags: sql, carto, csv

How to import .csv file to CartoDB using SQL, the data given below :

POINT      |    TOP_dm  |  BOTTOM_dm | X_RD     |     Y_RD

35AP7600   |    4418    | 4368    |    262053   | 467223

35AP7601   |    4267    | 4217   | 262000   |  467143

35AP7602  | 4358    | 4308  |  261780   |   467148

35AP7603    |   4209   | 4159   |  262098   |   467243

Answer (score 1):

### Using the SQL API

If it's dynamic data what you want to load with `SQL`, you should check CartoDB [SQL API](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/sql-api.html) and do a script that `INSERT` your csv data on CartoDB.

### Using the Dashboard

If it's static data you can just **drag the file** on your CartoDB **dashboard**

```
https://your_account_name.cartodb.com/dashboard
```

### Using the IMPORT API

There is also a very interesting [post on the Import API](http://blog.cartodb.com/post/54101913823/got-files-weve-got-a-import-api) that may be useful for you. The post includes a shell script to upload your files like this:

```
./cdb_import.sh <cdb_username> <api_key> <file_name>
```

Note: Take an account the disclaimer in the [cdb_import.sh script](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/script/cdb_import.sh). *It may be outdated*